# How can I make a bootstrap slide modal?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, slider

As in modals with arrows on each side.

I need to do this with 5 modals that will just go in a circle.

I would like to use only html/css, javascript, and bootstrap.

I'm not to familiar on how to use a js file and call it in an html file but i'm assuming it is similar to calling from a css file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/), part of the jQuery UI library. It provides modal dialog support that you can implement on the client side. There are some jsfiddle.net examples if you search. You could use arrow buttons on each side to navigate forward and backward.